# Cantor's Diagonal Argument - using induction on infinite row lengths?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I've read some simple explanations of Cantor's diagonal method.

It seems to be:

```
1) Changing the i-th value in a row.
2) Do the same to the next row with the (i+1)th element.
3) Now you get an element not in any other row. So add it to list.
4) This process never ends.
```

This looks very like induction since it uses the (n+1) trick.

However, induction only works for finite numbers.

And the row lengths are not finite.

So how did Cantor get around this?

Comment: To rigorously define a not enumerated sequence, indeed induction should be used, and its conclusion is basically (3).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Induction is not allowed for infinite numbers, I must not understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Cantor's diagonal proof is **not** infinite in nature, and neither is a proof by induction an infinite proof.

---

For Cantor's diagonal proof (I'll assume the variant where we show the set of reals between $0$ and $1$ is uncountable), we have the following claims:

- Every real number (between $0$ and $1$) has a representation as an infinite string $0.d_0d_1d_2d_3\cdots$, where each $d_i$ is a digit, i.e. $0$, $1$, $2$, ... or $9$.
- If the real numbers were countable, then we can make a function such that each real is assigned some natural number $n\in\Bbb N$ and vice versa, also known as a countable list of real numbers.
- It is possible to define a real that is not assigned any natural number: we define the $i$th digit of our new real to be $5$ if the $i$th digit of  the real number associated with the natural number $i$ is unequal to $5$, and otherwise we define the $i$th digit to be $6$. Note that we define this real all at once. We do not need to know the construction of earlier steps, so we do not use induction.
- This new real is not part of our list, since for any number of the list, there is some digit on which it disagrees.

None of these steps need you to do an infinite process. The only infinite thing we do is that we work with infinite sets of elements.

---

Induction in itself (which is unrelated to Cantor's diagonal argument) is also not an infinite process. To show that a property $\phi$ holds for all natural numbers, we prove that $\phi$ holds for $0$, and that if $\phi$ holds for $n$, then it holds for $n+1$. These are two finite proofs.

Then, to show that the property holds for *every* natural number, we pick an arbitrary number $m$. If we can show the property holds for $m-1$, then it must hold for $m$, so we try to show it holds for $m-1$. If it holds for $m-2$, then it must hold for $m-1$, so we try to show it holds for $m-2$. Et cetera, until we reach $m-m=0$. This is the base case, which we have already proved.

Therefore, we can show that the property holds for all natural numbers, since for any number, we only have to work back a finite number of steps to get to the base case.

---

As a sidenote, induction can be used on any [well-founded class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation), regardless of it being infinite or finite.

The trick is not that you show some property of interest for every element individually (which does indeed cost an infinite number of steps), but that you show that the property of an individual depends only on its predecessors having the property. You show "if all predecessors have the property, then this individual has the property".

If we then want to prove that an individual does not have the property, you would need to be able to find a predecessor that does not have the property.

In a well-founded set, there are no infinitely descending chains, so for any predecessor that is not the base case, we must be able to find a predecessor of this predecessor that does not have the property. We only can do this finitely many times, since a well-founded set has no infinitely descending chains.

It follows that eventually we will reach the base case, and for the base case we (presumably) have already proved that it has the property. Therefore our finite chain of predecessors must all have the property, which means our original element of interest must have the property.

Comment: You say: "each [all] real number is assigned some natural number", but this must be false, since you go on to create new real numbers. So you skipped some.  After some thinking, I still can't accept that $d_i$ refers to a number as i goes to infinity. I appreciate the arguments though.

Comment: @COOLBEANS No, I said **IF** the reals are countable, then ... In particular, since we can create new real numbers not on the list, this implies that the reals are **not** countable. That's exactly the point of Cantor's diagonal argument.

Comment: @COOLBEANS Each $d_i$ refers to a digit of the real number. There are $d_i$ for any natural number $i\in\Bbb N$, but there is no such thing as $i$ "going to infinity". We don't take any limits or something like that. There is no $d_\infty$. For example, $\pi$ has infinitely many digits, but it does not have an *infinite* digit: there is no limit digit that it tends to, and it makes no sense to talk about such a digit.

Comment: Consider $\pi-3=0.14159265\cdots$ and so on, then $d_0=1$, $d_1=4$, $d_2=1$, $d_3=5$, $d_4=9$, $d_5=2$, and so on. These values do not go to infinity, although there are infinitely many digits, for example $d_{2638764}$ is a digit of $\pi$, and indeed $d_n$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$ is a digit of $\pi$. But there is no $d_\infty$ (mainly because we don't need it, and because $\infty\notin\Bbb N$)

Comment: The new real is not on the list, so you say the reals are not countable. But why can't we just say that the list was simply incomplete to begin with? Alternatively why can't we say it wasn't countable at time t - 1, but now at time t we simply add one more onto the natural numbers and hey presto. It's infinite afterall, so this should be fine. There seems to be temporal element to this where you must go back and forth in discrete time steps.

Comment: @ Vsotvep In relation to $pi$, I will simply never understand how this is a meaningful statement, but I concede that it may be due to my own limitations: "these values do not go to infinity, although there are infinitely many digits"

Comment: @COOLBEANS I'm not sure what you mean with time. The goal of the proof is to show the reals are not countable, so we start by assuming it is countable, then we define a real number using the list (this is just a definition that sends an element of $\Bbb R^\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$, no need for induction), and we show that this real number is not equal to any member of the list by taking an arbitrary real from the list, say the $n$th real, and by how the function was defined we get that the $n$th digit of the $n$th real is different from our new real.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103748/discussion-between-vsotvep-and-coolbeans).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need induction to prove that the new number is different than any already listed number.

You have a construction for the new number. For any element in the list, there is some digit that is not the same, and based on where it is in the list, you can say exactly which one. This statement does not depend on previous digits differing for other numbers.

Comment: Even if you don't need induction, the proof should be invalid for same reason that  using induction with inf is invalid. The construction depends on getting to the end of an infinite row. The construction process would never terminate and we would never get a new number, right?

Comment: You aren't iteratively constructing a number. You just give a definition for what's in every position, and it simultaneously is all of those things.
The base 10 representation 1/7 doesn't take infinitely long to define.

Comment: Fine, but the definition can only apply to finite numbers - just like induction. You use phrase "every position", but infinite is not a number so it has no position. It's not finite, so it has no position.

Comment: Why can't the definition work for an infinitely long number? 1/7 certainly isn't finite in length, and you agree that its representation is well defined. The number is well-defined; every position has its own, definitive digit. If someone asks "what's in the nth position" for any n, you can say what digit is there. To be clear, you're not iteratively taking the first digit, then the first two, then the first three. You effectively are defining all the digits in parallel and then combining them in a single step.

Comment: You could argue that 1/7 isn't well defined since it's just a symbol for an endlessly repeating pattern of decimals. You can't tell me which integer is at the infinit-th position in this repeating decimal becuase infinity is not a number and thus cannot have a position. Hence my issue with Cantor's construction.

Comment: @COOLBEANS There is no infinite-th position. A real has infinitely many digits, but each digit is at a finite position. $1/7$ can be well-defined as the solution of the equation $x\cdot 7=1$.

Comment: I'm very opened minded and keen to learn, but "A real has infinitely many digits, but each digit is at a finite position. " sounds like a clear contradiction. I'll read your answer above carefully.

Comment: @COOLBEANS Think of it like this: there are infinitely many natural numbers (i.e. $0,1,2,3,\dots$), but there is no natural number that is larger than infinitely many other natural numbers. There is no largest natural number. We can find a natural number of arbitrarily large sizes, but we cannot find a natural number that is itself infinite.